# iFrame in XPage, load WebContent

Tags: iframe, xpages

My `myFolder/myDB.nsf` contains `WebContent/mySite/index.html`, an html file without any XPage code. The database is configured to only display web content after valid Notes login.

Now I want to embed this index.html in Notes Client in such a way that our users don't have to login to see it.

**How would I achieve this?**

I thought of doing it via `XPages/index.xsp`, an xsp containing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<iframe src="mySite/index.html" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</xp:view>
```

This works well when opening `http://myserver/myFolder/myDB.nsf/index.xsp` in Web Browser.

When opening it in Notes Client, an Error 404 is thrown.

When using

```
<iframe src="http://myServer/myFolder/myDB.nsf/mySite/index.html" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```

no error is thrown, but I still have to login, even though I already authenticated to notes.

Furthermore, when opening http:///myFolder/myDB.nsf/index.xsp, I have to login twice.

Answer (score 1):

In the notes client if you are referencing an XPiNC URL directly you need to add xsp/ on the front.

So in you case the URL would be

Whatever.nsf/xsp/index.html

You would need to programmatically detect the notes client as your user agent and add the xsp accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't.

Long answer: XPiNC behaves somehow different from a regular browser and IFrames are one of the areas. You can copy the body content of a standard HTML page into an XPage and it will  just display. for CSS/JS you put them into resources. This way it will display properly.

For the [base path](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) - you need to add it to the header. In XPages that is considered a resource, so you do:

```
   <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:headTag tagName="base">
        <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="/xx" />
            <xp:parameter name="target" value="_top" />
        </xp:this.attributes>
    </xp:headTag>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Then please give advice on how to add a base path to an XPage.

Comment: In short: don't. Use relative path

Comment: The HTML file is in a subdirectory, and is entry point to a web application with around 300 relative paths (JS, CSS, Images, WebServices), and most of them are even part of the framework used, and are hidden in minified Framework JS files. If I copy the content of the HTML file into the xsp, I *have to* set base path to point to the directory which the original HTML file is in.

Comment: XPiNC is NOT a standard web server. When you pry it open you will see, they do a few things to establish a session (and the user identity), these things are not available for static resources. Answer updated above